# How would translate this react-router3 router to react-router4?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I just want to see what the most optimized way to translate this react-router 3 code into react router 4

```
const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path='/' component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={CardsGrid}> . </IndexRoute>
                <Route path='/view/:postId' component= . {Single}></Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First chnage

```
// from
import { Router,Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';
// to
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Add `<Switch>` to List of Routes.The `<Route>` components are no longer exclusive. That means that even if one route matches the current url, nothing prevents a sibling route component from matching.Replace `<IndexRoute>` by a regular `<Route>`. To get a v3-like behavior, you must add the **exact** prop to your routes

```
const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App}>
               <Route exact component={CardsGrid}> . </Route>
               <Route exact path='/view/:postId' component= . {Single}></Route>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
```

Comment: thank you for this, but now i'm not getting any props from actions folder or from my mapStateToProps function.

Comment: @jabattack1 check whether your store is properly imported,exported and also check if the components are wraped with the HOC of connect()